# PHP Xpath: How to get the action URL from any method on a WSDL?

Tags: php, xpath, wsdl, simplexml

I am trying to recover the action URL from any arbitrary WSDL using only the action (and wsdl) desired:

```
$method = "consultarProcesso";
$wsdl = "https://webserverseguro.tjrj.jus.br/MNI/Servico.svc?wsdl";
$xmlWSDL = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($wsdl));
$xpath = "//*[local-name()='operation'][@name='$method']";
$result = $xmlWSDL->xpath($xpath);
var_dump($result[0]);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to get the node values from $result[0] to recover the desired value in this example:

```
http://www.cnj.jus.br/servico-intercomunicacao-2.2.2/consultarProcesso
```

What can I do to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to find the `input` element of interest directly using `xpath`. You can use the `local-name()` as you are currently:

```
$xpath = "//*[local-name()='operation'][@name='$method']/*[local-name()='input']";
```

or directly specify the namespace in the `xpath`:

```
$xpath = "//wsdl:operation[@name='$method']/wsdl:input";
```

Once you have the desired element, you can look through its namespaced attributes for the `Action`:

```
$result = $xmlWSDL->xpath($xpath)[0];
$namespaces = $result->getNameSpaces();
foreach ($namespaces as $ns) {
    if (isset($result->attributes($ns)['Action'])) $url = (string)$result->attributes($ns)['Action'];
}
echo $url;
```

Output:

```
http://www.cnj.jus.br/servico-intercomunicacao-2.2.2/consultarProcesso
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/BoEJT)

Comment: Nice ! But is there a dynamically way to the get action value without the static (in this case wsaw) namespace (or at least get the namespace dynamically)?

Comment: @celsowm I've modified the answer to search through all attribute namespaces of the result element

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve this info using the namespace arguments of both [`SimpleElement::children`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) and [`SimpleElement::attributes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php):

```
// Retrieve the `wsdl:` namespaced children of the operation
[$input, $output] = $result[0]->children('wsdl', true);

// Retrieve the `wsaw:`-namespaced attributes of the input element,
// then grab the one named Action
$actionAttribute = $input->attributes('wsaw', true)->Action;

// Convert its value into a string
$actionUrl = (string)$actionAttribute;
```

(Obviously this is over-commented for the purpose of this answer.)

Comment: Nice ! But is there a dynamically way to the get action value without the static (in this case wsaw) namespace (or at least get the namespace dynamically)?